# How do you silence console messages from `matplotlib` with `PyQt5` backend?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

#### background:

- i did pip install of

  - matplotlib 3.3.x
  - pyqt5
- some code to display figures with `pyplot`: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1,2,3]);plt.show();`
- whenever i run my code i get hundreds of lines of console spam:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: ...
...
qt.qpa.xcb: ...
qt.qpa.screen: ...
...
qt.qpa.screen: ...
qt.qpa.input.devices: ...
...
qt.qpa.input.devices: ...
qt.qpa.xcb: ...
qt.xkb.compose: ...
qt.qpa.fonts: ...
qt.accessibility.cache: ...
...
qt.accessibility.cache: ...
qt.text.font.db: ...
...
qt.text.font.db: ...
qt.qpa.gl: ...
...
qt.qpa.gl: ...
...
qt.qpa.events: ...
...
qt.qpa.events: ...
```

#### How do you silence the hundreds of console messages from `matplotlib` with `PyQt5` backend?

- a quick hack i found was to use the shell to redirect all stderr to `/dev/null` but then I will not see any error messages from other things like important warnings or errors from `numpy` so i need something better

Comment: Try something like `export QT_LOGGING_RULES='*.debug=false;qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror.warning=false;qt.qpa.xcb.xcberror.error=false;qt.qpa.xcb.warning=false;qt.qpa.xcb.error=false;qt.qpa.xcb=false'`

Comment: To build the full export out of console output : `var=''; for d in $(grep '^qt\.' test.txt | sort | uniq | cut -d ':' -f1); do var+="${d}.warning=false;"; done; echo "export QT_LOGGING_RULES='*.debug=false;$var"` perhaps changing `warning=false` to  `info=false` or `error=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `qt` debug to false as

```
os.environ["QT_LOGGING_RULES"] = '*.debug=false'
```

Or build more specific rules out of console output with

```
var=''; for d in $(grep '^qt\.' console.log | sort | uniq | cut -d ':' -f1); do var+="${d}.warning=false;"; done; echo "export QT_LOGGING_RULES='*.debug=false;$var'"
```

Then set it on python

```
os.environ["QT_LOGGING_RULES"] = '*.debug=false;qt.accessibility.cache.warning=false;qt.qpa.events.warning=false;qt.qpa.fonts.warning=false;qt.qpa.gl.warning=false;qt.qpa.input.devices.warning=false;qt.qpa.screen.warning=false;qt.qpa.xcb.warning=false;qt.text.font.db.warning=false;qt.xkb.compose.warning=false'
```

Tested with `os.environ["QT_LOGGING_RULES"] = '*.debug=true'` which gives many qt messages on console when running OP's code.